# How do I know if the profile for the user executing an application is a temporary profile?

Tags: c#, .net

In a C# application, I'm creating a signature using DSACryptoServiceProvider. If the user executing the apllication has a temporary profile, I get an exception: CryptographicException: "The profile for the user is a temporary profile."

The failure can be solved if I set DSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
But I first want to check if this change is needed. For that, I want in my code to check of the user has a temporary profile.

How can I check that?

Comment: not the same use case, but this is a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762021/programmatically-detect-that-user-has-logged-in-with-temporary-profile

Answer (score 2):

The only information I have found on this issue seems to point at clickonce deployment.

There is seemingly no known workaround since you should be using a non temporary profile in order to make the calls you are making ...

Apparently you appear to have answered your own question look here ...

> I want in my code to check of the user
>   has a temporary profile.
>
> How can I check that?

And the answer is ...

> If the user executing the apllication
>   has a temporary profile, I get an
>   exception: CryptographicException:
>   "The profile for the user is a
>   temporary profile."

Seems fairly straightforward, if you get that error you need to execute using a different profile.
You could have a test method that executes this code as a check before running through your actual code.

I have heard of one other option though, assuming this is within the context of an asp.net application you should be able to get the current profile like this ...

```
ProfileCommon profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;
```

From there you should be able to query the profile instance, i believe its a type of ProfileBase documented here ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151820(v=VS.100).aspx

Hope this helps clear things up a bit for you.