# Programmatically detect that user has logged in with temporary profile

Tags: windows

I have a program which uses some cryptographic primitives, which do not work when the user has been logged in with a temporary profile.  So far as I know, there is no workaround.

So I need my program to take alternate actions if there is a temporary profile.  I want to be able to detect this without resorting to trying the cryptographic operation and catching the exception.

Is there a way to determine that the current user's profile session is temporary (or mandatory), without detecting an error condition ?

Comment: From [this page, describing how to recover from a temporary profile,](https://kb.uwplatt.edu/page.php?id=33215) checking to see if there's an `S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxx-xxxx.bak` entry matching the current profile might be one way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [GetProfileType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762279(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

> Retrieves the type of profile loaded for the current user.
>
> `PT_MANDATORY`  - The user has a Mandatory User Profiles.
>
> `PT_TEMPORARY` - The user has a Temporary User Profiles; it will be deleted at logoff.

Comment: for some reason, my various google searches never turned this up, but it works fine.  and is more documented/supported than my registry hack method.